# How to give conditions and solve an integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations, condition

I want to solve an integration,

$\int  \frac{da}{\sqrt{\frac{8 \pi G \Lambda}{3}a^2 - K +c_1 a^{-(3k+1)}}}$

Here, how to give conditions k $\ge$ 0, G$>$ 0, $\Lambda$ $>$ 0 and K can be zero, positive or negative ? c$_1$ is a constant of integration (I mean c$_1$ is a constant which raised while solving some previous integration and I do not know value of c$_1$).  I couldn't find way to give these conditions so I just gave the input in Mathematica as below.

Integrate[$\frac{1}{Sqrt[\frac{8 \pi G \Lambda}{3} a^2 - K + c_1 a^{-(3k+1)}]}$,a]

But for this, in the output, Mathematica is keeping the integral as it is and not solving this integration. Can someone help me with this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The result indicates Mathematica cannot find a closed for for the antiderivative.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression generates for K=0 the squared expression

$$\text{PowerExpand}\left[\sqrt{\text{FullSimplify}\left[\left(\int \frac{a^{\frac{1}{2} (3 k+1)}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3} a^{3 k+3} (8 \pi  G \Lambda )-K a^{3 k+1}+c_1}} \, da\text{/.}\, \{K\to 0\}\right){}^2\right]}\right]$$

$$\frac{\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi }{3}} \sqrt{G} \sqrt{\Lambda } a^{\frac{3 (k+1)}{2}}}{\sqrt{c_1}}\right)}{\sqrt{6 \pi } \sqrt{G} (k+1) \sqrt{\Lambda }}$$

Verification

$$\text{Simplify}\left[\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\frac{\sinh ^{-1}\left(2 a^{\frac{3 (k+1)}{2}} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi  G \Lambda }{3 c_1}}\right)}{(k+1) \sqrt{6 \pi  G \Lambda }}\right){}^2=\left(\frac{a^{\frac{1}{2} (3 k+1)}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3} a^{3 k+3} (8 \pi  G \Lambda )-K a^{3 k+1}+c_1}}\text{/.}\, \{K\to 0\}\right){}^2\right]$$

```
  True
```

For $K\ne 0, c_1 \ne 0$ the odds to find a closed expression are low.

Comment: What happened to $K$?